# Facebook Requests Dialog: Sending Requests Failed

Tags: invite, facebook-app-requests

I just copy the source codes from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/, JavaScript Example section, change to my API ID, then I can see the Dialog.
but when I sent a Request to One or More Users, I always got the error:

An error occurred with xxxx. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 2
 API Error Description: Service temporarily unavailable
 Error Message: User can't send this request: Unknown error

Did anyone encountered this before?

Comment: "Service temporary unavailable" sounds a lot like a network communication issue - i.e. that it looks to your machine that the remote host is down.  Can you inspect the state of requests in e.g. Chrome's Network panel to see what it is that's failing, and why?

Comment: The issue is not only happen in one server.

Comment: The server should be irrelevant - if this is Javascript, it's going to be executing on the **client**.

Comment: Having now the same problem with our application. Several days ago it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook must have made some change over the past 12 hours. In your App Settings you'll have to add "App on Facebook" and this should allow your invites to work again.

I had an application that had the same problem and in my App Settings I only had "Website with Facebook Login" and "Page Tab" checked. When I added "App on Facebook" the invitations started to work again.

**Note:** Now, when a user sends an invite, the invitation will be directed to the app on Facebook as opposed to being directed to your website. For my application I had to add code to redirect from the Facebook App back to the tab.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this on my way.

You need a canvas app to use apprequest.

So click App on Facebook on the app setting page.

Create an index file for app including this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    top.location.href = 'REDIRECT_URL'
</script>
```

Write the app urls and done. The app request will work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems something is wrong with Facebook itself today. We are having a similar problem, I tried to google possible solutions and found your question asked 3 hours before.

Update: bug issue registered on Facebook with more than 30 repros - [apprequests return API Error Code: 2 Service temporarily unavailable](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/540196825997304?browse=search_508943d97b6433699181841)